# Questionmark in "if"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How can i write this Code in If Clause?

```
$('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success').text(data.msg).show(500);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the conditional operator in javascript.

```
(data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success'
```

means if the first part is true  `data.error === true` then you return 'error' elso you return 'success'

You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2):

```
var message = $('#message').removeClass();
if (data.error === true)
{
    message.addClass('error');
}
else
{
    message.addClass('success');
}
message.text(data.msg).show(500);
```

You could also put all those calls in the if-cases, but then you’d have to repeat the code all the time, so I split it up and used a local variable.